# How to prevent Firebase Realtime Database from blocking VPN connections?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, vpn

I was testing a Unity game of mine when I suddenly realized that my Firebase Realtime Database calls were hanging; after a bit of debugging, I've noticed it flawlessly works when I disable my [Mullvad](https://mullvad.net/en/) VPN, and consistently fails when my VPN is active.

Is there any way to configure the Realtime Database to accept connections from VPNs? Alternatively, is there anything different I can do in the code?

```
DatabaseReference fbref = FirebaseDatabase.GetInstance("https://foo.firebaseio.com/").RootReference.Child("path");
fbref.GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    Debug.LogError("Success!"); // Never reaches when VPN is active
)};
// No exceptions thrown
```

---

Edit:
After debugging for some time, I found that **enabling IPv6 in my VPN** fixed the issue locally - but if it happens to a user in production, I'm still at a loss.

Comment: Left an update - it seems like it was the VPN, but it would be great if I had some realtime debugging logs on Firebase so I could see if it was reaching Firebase at all

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

The Firebase backend is unlikely to be blocking the traffic here. What is much more like is that your VPN provider is not letting the traffic from your client through to the Firebase servers, for example because they don't allow Web Socket traffic (which is what Firebase depends on). You might want to check in with the provider, or check their documentation to see what sort of traffic is allowed and what isn't.